# Overlapped I/O error installing SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-8

A user of our software is attempting a normal installation on Windows V8.1 x64 (theoretically completely updated). As part of the install, SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 is normally installed as the back-end database.

This one user is currently getting an error 997 - Overlapped I/O operations is in progress. The relevant portion of the log file:

```
MSI (s) (40:90) [09:36:49:634]: SECREPAIR: New Hash Database creation complete.
MSI (s) (40:90) [09:36:49:634]: SECREPAIR: Crypt Provider not initialized. Error:0
MSI (s) (40:90) [09:36:49:642]: SECREPAIR: Crypt Provider not initialized. Error:0
MSI (s) (40:90) [09:36:49:643]: SECREPAIR: Crypt Provider not initialized. Error:0
MSI (s) (40:90) [09:36:49:643]: SECREPAIR: Crypt Provider not initialized. Error:0
MSI (s) (40:90) [09:36:49:643]: SECREPAIR: Crypt Provider not initialized. Error:0
MSI (s) (40:90) [09:36:49:643]: SECREPAIR: Crypt Provider not initialized. Error:997
MSI (s) (40:90) [09:36:49:643]: SECUREREPAIR: Failed to CreateContentHash of the file: Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2008R2\x86\Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlBrowserExtension.dll: for computing its hash. Error: 997
MSI (s) (40:90) [09:36:49:645]: SECREPAIR: Failed to create hash for the install source files
MSI (s) (40:90) [09:36:49:645]: SECUREREPAIR: SecureRepair Failed. Error code: 3e554415638
Action start 9:36:49: ProcessComponents.
Error 997. Overlapped I/O operation is in progress.
```

I have looked into the problems with KB2918614, and this patch is apparently not even installed - at least it doesn't show up in the list of installed fixes.

I disabled the running antivirus, and the error still occurs.

I did a manual install after downloading a fresh file from Microsoft - error still occurs.

I am now at a bit of a loss. I will continue searching for an answer online, but with all of the experience here - does anyone have any specific suggestions: things to check, things to install, things to disable, random voodoo idols to pray to, whatever.

Comment: I left out one factoid - the step of the installation where this fails is installing the support files... getting the timing information.

Comment: Looks like [you're the only one this has happened to](https://www.google.com/search?q=%2B%223e554415638%22). While it may not seem practical, have you given any thought to using a supported and more modern version of SQL Server? (It might be worth testing a more modern installation quick, that would potentially isolate 2008 R2 as the problem.)

Comment: Oh, good. I always like being that one person in the world with a given problem. It makes solutions much easier.

Comment: @LaughingVergil - [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31491531/1595565) may provide help.

Comment: @MaxVernon, you may be a lifesaver here. I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: Ignore previous post - it just randomly got farther in the install before erroring out. Sheesh.

Comment: What's the application that's using SQL Server as the backend?

Comment: It is a specialty pharmacy application. A very niche market app.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually located an answer to this. There are multiple steps that you need to perform to ensure that this does not occur, and any one of the items on the list can cause the issue.

- If any of these MS patches are installed, delete them. Any one can cause this issue

  - KB2918614 (The classic cause, but not the cause in this case)
  - KB3000988
  - KB3008627
  - KB3072630
- Rename or delete the folder C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18
- Rename or delete the folder C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18

In this particular case, one patch (KB3072630), and the two files all needed to be dealt with to fix the issue - or, to be more precise, I dealt with these three items before the issue was fixed.

Comment: Additionally, this error has been occasionally reported as occurring as caused by antivirus applications. Although I temporarily disabled the client's AV, it was not disabled at the time that the solution worked.